# Eclipse keeps finding wrong version of plugin dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins, eclipse-plugin, dependencies

I'm trying to add a plugin dependency to org.eclipse.emf.ecore, because I'm using Ecore to do some modeling for my plugin. The only problem is that when I try to add it, the only version that matches is 2.4 and I can't find that 2.4 jar anywhere on my system, so I have no idea why Eclipse can only find this version and where Eclipse finds it.

In Eclipse's own plugins directory, I have version 2.9, so why can't it find this version? I want to use v 2.9, but no clue how can get Eclipse to match that version.

Any help is welcome, this has me perplexed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse resolves dependencies against the currently set *target platform*. Make sure you have the right taget platform set, that includes `org.eclipse.emf.ecore` v. 2.9.

If you have not worked with the target platform before, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html) from Lars Vogel.